# Opencv install with cmake project configuration

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015, cmake

Hello I have installed the OpenCV 3.4.3 with Cmake as introduced in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0dPqxkd5wow). I've "build" ALL_BUILD project and then "build" the INSTALL project with debug and release. After that while adding opencv libraries to my project I couldn't find opencv_world343.lib inside `C:\opencv\build\install\x64\vc14\lib` directory. (Project Propery Pages>>Linker>>Input>>Additional dependencies). Other libraries seems OK. How can I integrate opencv with my project? Do I have to find 'opencv_world.lib' or if I add others one by one will be enough?

Comment: Is opencv_world343.lib present in C:\opencv\build\install\x64\vc14\lib ? If I recall correctly you can specify a CMake flag to build all OpenCV libraries and DLLs into a unique one that is called "world". Maybe you have built the separated LIB and DLLs (core, imgproc, and so on), in which case "world" is not created

Comment: Yes exactly as you said. How can I set the flag while building OpenCV? Or If I add one by one of their name, will be enough?

Comment: I've just found the flag -DBUILD_opencv_world=ON. Thanks.